# Upload files in Drone Pipeline to Google Cloud Storage using gcs plugin

Tags: google-cloud-storage, drone.io

I have a drone cicd pipeline that builds a npm project which I want to upload to Google Cloud Storage (gcs). I found a drone [gcs plugin](https://plugins.drone.io/plugins/gcs) which seems to be able to do so.
But I don't know what to use for the `token` parameter. The documentation says: "credentials to access Google Cloud Storage".

I have create a ServiceAccount and downloaded the json for it. My first attempt was to use the base64 encode json (as done with the [App Engine Plugin](https://github.com/nytimes/drone-gae)) but this failed with this error:

`failed to authenticate token: invalid character 'e' looking for beginning of value1`

Is this a oauth2 token? How can I create a token, so that drone-ci can upload the files to my bucket?

Comment: Have you tried to generate an access token from the [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)?

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I created an auth2 accesscode token but getting a similar error message: `failed to authenticate token: invalid character 'y' looking for beginning of value` - maybe I have to just use a container with a plain `gsutil` to copy files to gcs

Answer (score 2):

I see the GCS plugin is broken :(, but I have added another plugin Google [Cloud Auth](https://plugins.drone.io/plugins/google-cloud-auth) that allows you to pass SA json as string [secret](https://docs.drone.io/quickstart/cli/#emulate-secrets) and then use the auth plugin to activate the SA based auth.

You can then mount the ~/.config/gcloud in all the required steps and do the required gcloud tasks.  For an example check https://plugins.drone.io/plugins/google-cloud-run that uses this method.

I hope this helps you.